# create TVC ("Table Value Constructor") script from temp table (same like SSMSBoost provides select script )

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My requirement is I need to create data select script from table/or complex query result. (same like SSMSBoost provides to generate select script from query)
Here I have developed logic for it in TSQL.

OR in other word, what ever result is displayed in DATAGRID OF SSMS, I wan't that data as a select script.

Example : below is the result of any query

[image]

from above result I want to generate it's select script as below.

```
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES 
(256087,'MCD','217647-A33')
,(256526,'MCD','217647-A33')
,(256777,'HARP','217647-A33')
,(256794,'MCD','217647-A33')
,(256835,'MCD','217647-A33')
 ) VTE
([ID],[prod],[provn&qw])
```

---

In SSMSBOOST if you right click on result datagrid and click on select script than it will generate such script for you. Same thing I want to do without SSMS Boost.

My Working code :
save your query result into temp table, assign it to @TBL and run it will generate result.

I want to do this thing without saving data into temp table same as SSMSBoost.  Let me know if you have any more ideas.

```
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TBL VARCHAR(20) = '#TEMP1';

;WITH CTE as
(
    SELECT distinct t.name as SYStype, '['+C.name+']' COLNAME, C.max_length , column_id
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns C
    INNER JOIN sys.types T on T.system_type_id = C.system_type_id
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..'+@TBL)
    AND t.name <> 'sysname'
)
,LINES AS
( --CREATES SINGLE LINES 
SELECT distinct LN = concat('SELECT CONCAT('',('',', SUBSTRING((SELECT ','','',' + 
    CASE WHEN SYStype in('nvarchar','varchar','datetime','time','date','uniqueidentifier') THEN CONCAT('CASE WHEN ',COLNAME,' IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE CONCAT('''''''',',' REPLACE(' ,COLNAME,','''''''','''''''''''')',','''''''') END') 
    ELSE  CONCAT('CASE WHEN ',COLNAME,' IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE CAST(',COLNAME,' AS VARCHAR(20)) END') END +''
    --ELSE COLNAME END 
FROM CTE
order by column_id FOR XML path (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),6,90000),','')'')',CHAR(10),' FROM '+@TBL)
)
select @QUERY=
concat('SELECT ''SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ''',CHAR(10),'UNION ALL',CHAR(10),
 LN 
,CHAR(10),'UNION ALL',CHAR(10),'SELECT '' ) VTE', CHAR(10),'(',
(SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+COLNAME FROM  CTE order by column_id FOR XML path (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),2,2000)) ,')''')
FROM LINES

EXECUTE (@QUERY);
```

Comment: I have read this 2-3 times now and it makes less sense to me each time. What are you trying to do? And I can't even pretend to understand what you mean about removing the first comma.

Comment: Try to run given code, it will generate "select script" of your temp table., It will help to move some selected data from one database to another which is not linked. Also Hepl me to update data in TFS.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I still don't have any idea what you are trying to do. The dynamic sql you have here is a real mess. Perhaps if you could explain what you want to happen it would make a LOT more sense.

Comment: 1) Take any SQL table and save its result to temp table example : #TEMP1 and run above code, It will generate table's  select script, If you remove just first comma, it will give you result same as your table. First please try to run it.

Comment: Why do you need to generate a script like this anyway? What are you REALLY trying to accomplish. This seems like a classic xy problem to me. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: This functionality is provided by SSMSBoost , and I need to use it without SSMSBoost. In SSMSBoost, what ever query you have written you will get its select script.

Comment: But for what purpose? You can generate data from your table so much easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176156/discussion-between-jigar-parekh-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally here is the query which can generate Transact-SQL table value constructor from any temp table

1. just replace #Temp with your temp table name
2. Optional you can provide column for order by

here is the final query

```
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TBL VARCHAR(20) = '#TEMP';
DECLARE @ORDERBYCOL VARCHAR(20) = '1';--Optional replace 1 with your column in which order  by    

    ;WITH CTE as
    (
        SELECT distinct t.name as SYStype, '['+C.name+']' COLNAME, C.max_length , column_id
        FROM tempdb.sys.columns C
        INNER JOIN sys.types T on T.system_type_id = C.system_type_id
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..'+@TBL)
        AND t.name <> 'sysname'
    )
    ,LINES AS
    (
        SELECT distinct LN = concat('SELECT CONCAT(CASE WHEN _ROW_NUM_=1 THEN '' '' ELSE '','' END, ''('','
            , SUBSTRING(
                    (SELECT ','','',' + 
                        CASE WHEN SYStype in('nvarchar','varchar','datetime','time','date','uniqueidentifier') THEN CONCAT('CASE WHEN ',COLNAME,' IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE CONCAT('''''''',',' REPLACE(' ,COLNAME,','''''''','''''''''''')',','''''''') END') 
                        ELSE  CONCAT('CASE WHEN ',COLNAME,' IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE CAST(',COLNAME,' AS VARCHAR(20)) END') END +''
                        --ELSE COLNAME END 
                    FROM CTE
                    order by column_id FOR XML path (''), TYPE)
                    .value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),6,90000)
        ,','')'')',CHAR(10),' FROM ',
        '(
            SELECT TOP 1000000 * , _ROW_NUM_ = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1) )
            FROM ',@TBL,' ORDER BY ',@ORDERBYCOL,'
        ) CTE ' )
    )
    select @QUERY=
    concat('SELECT ''SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ''',CHAR(10),'UNION ALL',CHAR(10),
     LN 
    ,CHAR(10),'UNION ALL',CHAR(10),'SELECT '' ) VTE', CHAR(10),'(',
    (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+COLNAME FROM  CTE order by column_id FOR XML path (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),2,2000)) ,')''')
    FROM LINES
    
    EXECUTE (@QUERY);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:
[EDITED - my apologies, previous answer was incomplete]
@mystring_1 would be your original DDL string.
Assumes the first comma will always be at position 25.

```
declare @mystring_1 varchar(100) ,
        @mystring_2 varchar(100) 
SET @mystring_1 = 'SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ' + CHAR(13) + ',' + ' other stuff , '
SET @mystring_2 = STUFF(@mystring_1, 25, 1, '')
PRINT @mystring_1
PRINT '-----'
PRINT @mystring_2
```

Comment: DDL string will be more than 8000 character, depends on table. else it will be easy to remove comma.

Comment: I have joined those who have read and re-read your question and still don't understand it.

Comment: please try to use SSMS Boost, and see its feature than you will be able to understand it.